# assign permission to group managed service account

Tags: active-directory, scheduled-tasks, service-accounts

I have been advised that it is better to run a scheduled task as a Group Managed Service Account (gMSA) rather than as a domain user account. I can find plenty of information about how to create the gMSA, and how to configure the scheduled task to run as that gMSA, but all of the tutorials and training I have found stop there. I can't find any information on how to assign permission to that gMSA.

For example, a scheduled task needs permission to write to a folder. Normally, if the scheduled task is running as a domain user, I would go into the properties for that folder and set the security so that the domain user has write permission. But I am finding that I cannot give a gMSA permission in the same way.

What am I misunderstanding about gMSAs?

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I came here to ask.   What are the odds that this would be a 3 year  old unanswered question?

Answer (score 1):

> But I am finding that I cannot give a gMSA permission in the same way.

Right click folder > Security > Edit > Object Types... > Service Accounts > OK.

When selecting a principal you have to first set "Object Types..." to include Service Accounts, by default it doesn't include them in your search. Then you should be able to use it as a principal for your your file system access controls.

Answer (score 0):

I have not find a way to assign permissions to a GMSA directly to the file system. My workaround is to add the GMSA account to an AD group and then assign permissions to the group.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31081510)